# How to trigger the java shutdown hook for a keep running process?

Tags: java, tomcat, process, pid, shutdown

UPDATED:
Now, to get things clear, the situation is:  there is a project which is started only by calling the main() function in A class, and in the main() a shutdown hook is added.
The A starts many other worker threads and they keep running until the ShutdownHook is executed. 
My question is how to let  the shutdown hook be executed? We used to use kill -9 PID to kill the process. And I am not sure will the shutdown hook  be executed with directly kill.
I searched a lot, most say with kill -9 the proper shutdown will be ignored? But my colleague said we have been using this way to stop the service for long time...I am now totally confused.

```
public class A {
//...omitted unrelevant
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final A ctrl = new A(configName, routerId);
    ctrl.startup();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
            public void run() {
                if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                    logger.warn("Kill signal received, starting shutdown...");
                }
                ctrl.shutdown(); //calling the real shutdown
                if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                    logger.warn("Shutdown done, going down.");
                }

                Set<Thread> threadSet=Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
                String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
                    if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                        logger.warn("Killing : " + thread.getName() + " " + thread.getClass().getName());
                    }
                    if (!thread.getName().equals(currentThreadName)) {
                        thread.stop();
                    }
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
    }
}

// ...

public void shutdown() {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("requesting shutdown");
    }

    for (Worker w : worker) {
        w.requestShutdown();
    }
    for (Thread t : workerThreads) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("shutdown finished");
    }

}}
```

Comment: `kill -9` is the only Unix signal that cannot be intercepted by a process and as a result will not trigger any shutdown hook. It's not clear what you're asking from your description, perhaps if you post your code it will become clearer what your problem is.

Comment: A process killed with `SIGKILL` (which is what `kill -9` does) won't have any chance of running any shutdown activities. The signal can't be caught, and the process will be simply terminated. If you need a "softer" termination signal, use one intended for the purpose (`SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`).

Comment: @kiheru okay, then do you know how to let it execute the proper shutdown without changing the original code?

Comment: Shutdown hooks should work fine as long you do not use `SIGKILL`. `kill -INT` would send `SIGINT`, and when using that the shutdown hook should be executed. I'd reserve `-9` for real emergencies, where the system for some reason can't be shutdown cleanly. `Thread.stop()` is deprecated btw, for [reasons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: Okay, this is good. But another problem comes. How can I find the pid of this process when it is ran through Tomcat. I can only find the processID of the whole tomcat. If i stop that one it will kill other services in tomcat together.@kiheru

Comment: That's something I'm not familiar with, so I can't help with it. You'll probably find something useful on the net.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), 'If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SIGINT signal, as suggested by kiheru. That is what is sent when you press Ctrl+C.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: `kill -9` is very different from other `kill` commands. `kill -9` is an instruction to the OS to remove a process from the scheduler and take away all of it's memory. Other `kill` commands pass a signal to the running process and let the process decide how to handle it. That is why `kill -9` always works, even when the process is hung.

Extra Detail: On Linux, the regular `kill` command, with no parameters other than the PID, is a TERM signal, and will cause the shutdown hook to execute.

To demonstrate, consider:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RunShutdownHook extends Thread {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Setting the shutdown hook.");
        final Thread nonDaemonThread = new RunShutdownHook();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Starting shutdown hook.");
                nonDaemonThread.interrupt();

                // Wait to give the interrupted thread a chance to gracefully exit.
                for (int i = 0; i < 10 && nonDaemonThread.isAlive(); i++) {
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // We can ignore the InterruptedException because this
                        // thread is about to exit.
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Finishing shutdown hook.");
            }
        });

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Starting the non-daemon thread.");
        nonDaemonThread.setName("NonDaemonThread");
        nonDaemonThread.start();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Thread exiting.");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Starting thread.");
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Sleeping.");
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Awakened.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Interrupted.");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Thread exiting.");
    }
}
```

Interrupted with Ctrl-C:

```
$ java RunShutdownHook          
main - Setting the shutdown hook.
main - Starting the non-daemon thread.
main - Thread exiting.
NonDaemonThread - Starting thread.
NonDaemonThread - Sleeping.
NonDaemonThread - Awakened.
NonDaemonThread - Sleeping.
^CThread-1 - Starting shutdown hook.
NonDaemonThread - Interrupted.
NonDaemonThread - Thread exiting.
Thread-1 - Finishing shutdown hook.
$
```

Running `kill <PID>` from another terminal:

```
$ java RunShutdownHook   
main - Setting the shutdown hook.
main - Starting the non-daemon thread.
main - Thread exiting.
NonDaemonThread - Starting thread.
NonDaemonThread - Sleeping.
NonDaemonThread - Awakened.
NonDaemonThread - Sleeping.
Thread-1 - Starting shutdown hook.
NonDaemonThread - Interrupted.
NonDaemonThread - Thread exiting.
Thread-1 - Finishing shutdown hook.
$
```

Running `kill -9 <PID>` from another terminal:

```
$ java RunShutdownHook
main - Setting the shutdown hook.
main - Starting the non-daemon thread.
main - Thread exiting.
NonDaemonThread - Starting thread.
NonDaemonThread - Sleeping.
NonDaemonThread - Awakened.
NonDaemonThread - Sleeping.
zsh: killed     java RunShutdownHook
$
```

`kill -9` does not activate the shutdown hook.